# A project with an output type of class library cannot be started

Tags: c#

I am given a source control which comprises class libraries only.
How should I run the project?

Comment: The thing that makes a library a library is the fact that it doesn't have an entry point. You can't "start" libraries, and by extension you can't "start" a project that contains only libraries

Comment: create a console application that references and uses your dll's and step through it as you run.

Comment: You can only build (F6) class library. You cannot run it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't debug a class library directly.  If you think about it, where would it start running, i.e. what method?  You need to have an executable (console application, winforms, wpf, etc.) project to run, which would typically reference your class library.

If you have one of those in your solution, right-click on it in the solution explorer and select "Set as Startup Project".  Then try again.